# Show whether or not this is a norm.

Tags: normed-spaces

Show whether $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defines a normed vector space on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For $(\underline{x}) = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$,

$F(\underline{x}) = (\sum_{i=1}^{3} |x_i|^\frac{1}{2})^2$.

So at first glance this seems similar to the Euclidean norm, only with the powers swapped over. However I'm fairly sure this contradicts the triangle inequality for norms but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: Well, you just need a counterexample. Think of $a=(1,0,0)$ and $b=(0,1,0)$. Then $F(a+b) = 4 > 2 =F(a) + F(b) $.

Comment: [How do you prove the p-norm is not a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when 0<p<1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102385/how-do-you-prove-the-p-norm-is-not-a-norm-in-mathbb-rn-when-0p1)

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I tried a counter example but forgot to square at some stage.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an even simpler example you can use, but this one works.

Consider the three points $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$ and $(2,2,2)$. Attempt to find the distances between them and apply the triangle inequality, and you should get something like $$1 + \left(1+2\sqrt{2}\right)^2\geq 18$$

or approximately

$$ 15.6 \geq 18$$

which is ridiculous.

Comment: Peter's example in the comments above is much simpler.