# Show that $\rho(x)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^{1/2} \right)^2$ is not a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Show that $\rho(x)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^{1/2} \right)^2$ is not a norm

It clearly satisfies the first two properties, that it be nonnegative and $\rho(ax)=|a|\rho(x)$. So it must not satisfy the triangle inequality: $\rho(x+y)\le \rho(x)+\rho(y)$ must fail for some x, y.

Choose $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$ as some vectors and plug it into the formula.

$$\begin{split}\rho(x+y)&?\rho(x)+\rho(y)\\
[(x_1+y_2)^{1/2}+(x_2+y_2)^{1/2}]^2&?[x_1^{1/2}+x_2^{1/2}]^2+[y_1^{1/2}+y_2^{1/2}]^2\\
x_1+y_1+x_2+y_2+2\sqrt{(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)}&?x_1+x_2+2\sqrt{x_1x_2}+y_1+y_2+2\sqrt{y_1+y_2}\end{split}$$

Compare the parts that are different:

$$\begin{split}2\sqrt{(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)}&?2\sqrt{x_1x_2}+2\sqrt{y_1y_2}\\
2\sqrt{x_1x_2+x_1y_2+y_1x_2+y_1y_2}&?2(\sqrt{x_1x_2}+\sqrt{y_1y_2})\\
x_1x_2+x_1y_2+y_1x_2+y_1y_2&?x_1x_2+y_1y_2+2\sqrt{x_1x_2y_1y_2}\\
x_1y_2+y_1x_2&?2\sqrt{x_1x_2y_1y_2}\\
x_1^2y_2^2+y_1^2x_2^2+2x_1y_1x_2y_2&?4x_1x_2y_1y_2\end{split}$$

If $(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)$ and $(y_1,y_2)=(0,1)$ we get $1$ on the LHS and $0$ on the RHS thus the triangle equality fails and this is not a norm because we have found a counterexample.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You really don't need to do all that work just compute directly $\rho((1,1)^T), \rho((1,0)^T)$ and $\rho((0,1)^T).$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102385/42969

Comment: I wanted to verify the solution and am glad I did because of Thomas's amazing insight for a noob like me. Also, thanks for the link.

Comment: If you know the first two properties, then the triangle inequality is equivalent to the statement that $\{x\mid \rho(x)<1\}$ is convex. That givens an intuitively look at a function $\rho$ as a norm. You can look at a shape of the $\{x\mid \rho(x)=1\}.$